# How to count number of clients in room socketio 4.4.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i'm trying to limit the number of users i can have in one room but i need to get the number of users currently in the room.

This is what my server.js looks like

```
socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId) => {
         var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId];
         var numClients = typeof clients !== "undefined" ? clients.length : 0;
        console.log(numClients);
        if (numClients === undefined || numClients < 3) {
            console.log('Joined room ' + roomId);
            socket.join(roomId);
            socket.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);
            io.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', userId);
        } else {
            console.log('room_full');
            // socket.broadcast.to(userId).emit('room_full', 'for your eyes only');
        }
        
    });
```

This is the error i get in my logs

```
...
 console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId].length)
2022-04-01T02:08:14.237151+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                      ^
2022-04-01T02:08:14.237151+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-04-01T02:08:14.237152+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
...
```

I have socketio@4.4.1

Comment: usually your roomId is not valid, so io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId] returns undefined, and you cannot access a property of an undefined object.

Comment: btw you can use optional chaining(?.) to stop your app from crashing... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @CodeJonSnow I've implemented optional chanining, it doesn't crash my app anymore. Thank you. However, even after one person has joined and the second person joins, `console.log(numClients);` in my code returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

this code may help you

```
var activeUsers = new Set();
var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId];
activeUsers.add(clients);
console.log("active Users", activeUsers);
```

Output

```
active Users Set(1) { '62039f336226f0fdc7e90915' }
```

Answer (score 0):

return all Socket instances of the main namespace

```
const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();
```

return all Socket instances in the "room1" room of the main namespace

```
const sockets = await io.in("room1").fetchSockets();
```

return all Socket instances in the "room1" room of the "admin" namespace

```
const sockets = await io.of("/admin").in("room1").fetchSockets();
```

this also works with a single socket ID

```
const sockets = await io.in(theSocketId).fetchSockets();
```